# Inconsistent behaviour between lists containing multiline text links

Tags: feature-request, bug

SE sites typically have the anchor tag inside the h3 tag.  For example:

```
<h3><a href="/questions/332282/add-strings-from-moderator-revision-redaction-approval-block-into-transifex-or" class="question-hyperlink">Add strings from moderator
```

One can point the cursor and click like this:

[image: Cursor is a finger pointing to the text]

But on multi-line text, there is a very annoying strip where the cursor won't work:

[image: Cursor is a standard arrow pointing between the text]

Notice that in the first case the cursor is a finger pointing to the text, and clicking will work as intended, but in the second case the cursor is the standard cursor and clicking will have no effect.

If there is no real need for things to be done this way, it would be much nicer if the `<a>` and `<h3>` tags were reversed.

This of course is only an example.  I imagine the same problem occurs with anchors inside other tags too.

---

UPDATE:

Interestingly, in the standard lists that appear in the right column, even though the "Frequently Asked" list has the same problem:

[image: Has gap]

just below it, the "Hot Network Questions" list *works correctly*:

[image: No gap]

So, whether the "gap" behaviour is considered a bug or intended design, there is definite inconsistency in behaviour between those two adjacent lists.  And **that inconsistency *is* a bug**.

Comment: I'm curious; what do the downvotes that this item has received mean?  That it's _not_ a problem, that it _is_ a problem but not worth considering, or _what_?